# Applying to another department from within the same company

Tags: employment

I work for a massive US company. Aside from the "regular" company, they also have a *Federal services* division. I'm an engineer for the West sector of their regular services.

I want to apply to a position in Federal, but I don't want the company to know. They supposedly *encourage* employees to search for opportunities within the company, but I don't buy that.

Is that possible?

Comment: Not sure why anyone is down voting this; it's a perfectly reasonable question and not an uncommon situation in larger companies. Nor why there was a close vote; yes, the details are company specific but the strategy isn't.

Comment: Joe, I'm not sure why you "don't buy that". If you're a good employee the company wants to have you transfer (if possible) rather than leave to find a job you like better. And most companies like to see folks get exposure to a number of different parts of the business, especially if you aim to be in a managerial position at some point.

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't possible to apply for a job in a company without the company knowing.

On the other hand, there is absolutely nothing wrong with telling your management "Hey, I'm very interested in that project. Any objections to my seeing if they can use me?" If you have been in your current department for a while, they may be sorry to lose you and may want you to stay for a few more months to transfer knowledge and get past an immediate deadline, but they probably won't be upset by the request. They'd rather see a good employee move elsewhere in the company than see you leave the company to find the job you want.

Be aware that the difficulty of a transfer is often proportional to how many steps up and back down the management chain it is from your current department to the new one, since that's roughly how many managers need to approve it. Moving to an adjacent department or project is usually fairly easy. Changing divisions is more difficult, and may require that you also interview with a lot of "closer" departments as this bubbles up the management tree and percolates back down.

I did essentially this early in my own career, moving from mainframe hardware development to software research and changing divisions in the process. It can be done, and isn't something you need to be ashamed of trying or afraid to talk about, assuming halfway sane managers.

Just don't expect it to be fast, and remember that you still have to at least informally interview with the target group and convince them that you're worth adding to their budget rather than looking for the same skills outside the company.

Relax. Go for it.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but I've only been here a year. And if I want to leave, then _they'll know_ there's something wrong and they'll want to find a _way_ to _make things right_. I don't want to go through that unnecessary waste of time.

Comment: The other issue is that, once they know I want to go elsewhere, they'll _know_ that I'm looking for alternatives. What will happen if they don't take me at the other department?

Comment: They know that you are interested in a specific project. That doesn't imply you will jump ship if you don't get reassigned. At most, they know that you are thinking about where you want your career to go and staying aware of what's happening in the industry. If you are performing well in your current position, they have no reason to get rid of you early. Unless your boss is a martiner, they will understand and may even assist. (Note: Do as I say, not as I did -- I missed several chances to get involved in something new because I was overly focused on what I was currently doing.)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to apply to a position in Federal, but I don't want the company
> to know. They supposedly encourage employees to search for
> opportunities within the company, but I don't buy that.
>
> Is that possible?

It is possible for the company to make moving projects/teams/divisions possible without tipping off your current leadership.

I worked for one that did it this way. When you applied for another position internally, they never contacted your current manager and co-workers. They relied on  your resume, your outside references, your interview, and the performance reviews.

Only when it was time to determine start date on the new position did your current manager know.

from one of your comments:

> I've only been here a year. And if I want to leave, then they'll know
> there's something wrong and they'll want to find a way to make things
> right. I don't want to go through that unnecessary waste of time.

By blocking your current leadership from knowing, the only negotiating that went on was picking the last day on your current contract.

How do you know if they do keep it quiet? Ask somebody who has transferred. Ask how their old manager was told. Or did their old manager discover it.

Note: you have been there a year. Some companies block internal transfers if you have been on your current position less than X months. That is to stop people from jumping every few months, which wastes company money. Check your corporate policies.